# How to limit the length using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use regex to verify the length(6-18)'s string:

```
var reg = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z_0-9]{6, 18}$')

var res = reg.test('aaaaaa')

console.log(res)   // but there I get false
```

whether my regex is write wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a rogue space in the bracketed quantity.  Remove it and your code will work:

```js
var reg = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z_0-9]{6,18}$');  // NOT {6, 18}
var res = reg.test('aaaaaa');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative if you don't want to use Regular Expressions:

```js
function isCorrectLength(str, min, max) {
  return str && typeof str === 'string' && str.length >= min && str.length <= max;
}

console.log(isCorrectLength('testing', 6, 18));
console.log(isCorrectLength('test', 6, 18));
```